# Error with initialization of firebase while running Vue-CLI app

Tags: firebase, webpack, vue-cli

I'm pretty new to Vue-CLI and Firebase. I've been using Firebase for authorization and Firestore DB. I Have Encountered the following error while trying to render my application in browser:

`Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_firebase___default.a.auth is not a function`

From what I've looked, it seems like there's something wrong with how I am initializing Firebase, but I couldn't find the problem.

Here is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let app
let fireBaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ***,
    authDomain: ***,
    databaseURL: ***,
    projectId: ***,
    storageBucket: ***,
    messagingSenderId: ***
  };

firebase.initializeApp(fireBaseConfig)

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if(!app){
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      components: { App },
      template: '<App/>'
    })
 }
   });

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
  firestore.settings(settings);

export { firestore }
```

Comment: You say the problem is in Chrome specifically. Do you say this because you don't have the same problem with other browsers?

Comment: No, it was also happening in Firefox. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit that.

Comment: Note that I moved the error message into the body of the question where it is more easily grokked by humans.

Comment: So finally I found a solution: You should delete your node_modules folder and package-lock file, and clear npm cache. Then, reinstall everything and it should work out just fine.